# Emulating Python 2.0 pandas panel with multi-index data-frame in 3.0

Tags: pandas, panel, multi-index

thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
dictionary =

{'A':          'a'     'b'           
 Date                                                   
 1997-09-11  1060  1071    
 1997-09-12  1060  1078       

....
 'B':          'a'     'b'                
 Date                                                          
 1997-09-11  2900  2931      
 1997-09-12  2919  2954     
...}
```

For Python 2 I create pandas panel:

```
dataPanel = pd.Panel.from_dict(dictionary, intersect=False, orient='minor')
```

Assign global variables.

```
c = dataPanel.a
d = dataPanel.b
```

Define formulas.

```
cd = c - d
```

Create df:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([cd], join='outer', axis = 1))
df

Date         'A'    'B'
1997-09-11   11     31      
1999-09-12   18    -35
```

Challenge is recreating pandas Panel environment with a multi-index data frame in 3.0.  I've tried a host of things and can't seem get there.

For instance, nested dict to data frame, then to multi-index dataframe:

```
df= {k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k,v in stockDataDict.items()}
df = pd.concat(stockDataDict, axis=1) 

df.index

DatetimeIndex(['1997-09-11', '1997-09-12',
               ...
               '1999-07-01', '1999-07-02'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=4, freq=None)
```

Create multi-index

```
idf = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df)
idf

MultiIndex([( 1060,  1071),
            ( 1060,  1078),
            ( 2900,  2931),   
            ( 2919,  2954)],
           names=[('A', 'a'), ('A', 'b'), ('B', 'a'), ('B', 'b')], length=4)
```

My sense is I'm incorrectly passing index/and or columns names from dictionary to df, eliminating chance of getting idf correct.

Two goals:

Break the MultiIndex names into say ('A'), ('B'), ('a'), ('b'), to enable say:

```
c = idf.a
d = idf.b
cd - c-d
```

to get:

```
Date         'A'    'B'
1997-09-11   11     31      
1999-09-12   18    -35
```

Thanks again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it right.

Arrange nested dict for data frame.

```
dict_of_df = {k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k,v in stockDataDict.items()}
df = pd.concat(stockDataDict, axis=0)
df

            Open        Close   
Date                            
ES  
1997-09-11  1060.750    1071.750    
1997-09-12  1060.000    1078.500
```

Name indexes:

```
df = df.rename_axis(['Symbol','Date'])
```

Create data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Assign variables:

```
o = df.Open
c = df.Close
```

Create series and formula:

```
zs = (c-o)
```

Unstack data Frame (major clue!)

```
df1 = zs.unstack(level=0) 
df1
Symbol                ES
Date

1997-09-11            11.5
1997-09-12           -18.5
```